# Quando uso essa permissão ocorre um erro no TODO. O que eu faço?

Tags: java, android

Quando uso essa permissão ocorre um erro no TODO. O que eu faço?

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return TODO;
            }
```

Este é o erro:

> Error:(40, 20) error: incompatible types: unexpected return value

Comment: Tem que retornar alguma coisa então. O que seria TODO?

Comment: mano vc sabe pra q serve essa permissao?

Comment: esse TODO ele cria automaticamente

Comment: Localização. Mas sua dúvida não parece ser sobre isso. Você não parece entender o que está fazendo. Você copiou e colou?

Comment: nao sei mesmo nao. Estou tentando fazer um projeto q retorna a latitude e longitude atual e quando uso o LocationManager.requestLocationUpdate() ele pede essa permissao.

Comment: Procure aqui no site sobre pedir permissões no Android 6. Você tem que entender o que está fazendo antes de perguntar por que o código não funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro ocorre pois está retornando uma variável que não existe !

Além de verificar se existe a permissão é necessário solicitar, caso não exista!

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static final void checarPermissao(final Activity activity) {
    if(null == activity) return;

    // VErifica se você tem uma permissão específica.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Obtém se você deve mostrar  a UI com justificativa para solicitar uma permissão.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Por favor, permita o acesso a localização", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            // Chama a Activity que irá solicitar a permissão ao usuário
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Observe isso:

```
return TODO;
```

Quem é `TODO`? Que bicho é esse? O que come? Onde vive?

A resposta é que `TODO` vem do inglês `to do` que significa "**a fazer**". Ou seja, isso é algo que foi gerado automaticamente para dizer que o código está incompleto e que você tem que colocar alguma coisa lá.

Entretanto você não colocou nada e deixou o `TODO` do jeito que estava. O compilador vai tentar ver isso como um nome de variável, mas esta variável não existe, e portanto você vai tomar um erro de compilação.

Além disso, veja o comentário que antecede isso:

```
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
```

Traduzindo para o português:

```
            // A FAZER: Considere chamar
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // aqui para requisitar as permissões que estiverem faltando, e então sobreescrever
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // para tratar o caso onde o usuário concede a permissão. Veja a documentação
            // de ActivityCompat#requestPermissions para mais detalhes.
```